# How to avoid symfony2 to automatically load one-to-one relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a User class which have a One-to-One association with another entity Result

Everything is working fine but anytime I load a set of users, i can see in the profiler that for each user symfony makes a query to load his result.

I don't need the result everywhere, and i manually retrieve it when i need.
I came to believe that symfony loads one-to-one relations automatically with the entity but didn't find out how to avoid it.

My classes :

```
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Result", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
     protected $result;
}

class Result {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="result")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
 }
```

----- EDIT -----

I found out that it only happen when the User entity is loaded in a formbuilder :

```
$builder
    ->add('user', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ThemBaseBundle:User',
        'query_builder' => function($repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->orderBy('a.lastName', 'ASC');
        },
        'property' => 'fullName'
    ))
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but probably one-to-one relations are fetched eagerly by default. Try switching the fetching strategry to lazy. See [this section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=eager#onetoone) for more information.

Comment: I found out it only happens in the Form, i edited my question.

Comment: The only solution i found was to put the joining column on the User entity, not on the Result entity.

That's quite a weird behavior, but at least i don't get so many queries now.